# PHP coding, How to handle javascript & within javascript in the same piece of source code?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Typically, I inject so many javascript in the website. But suddenly, the client told me that he can't render the website correctly, so I check it. I realize that he didn't enable javascript on his side.
So, my question is, should I need two places of source code? one is: `index_with_js.php`, and one is `index.php`, all files separate with *js* and *non js* version?
It is not a difficult job, but just make people insane to doing this. Any better suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Really, you should make your website degrade gracefully. Its not too difficult just involves changing the way you work a little bit.

I always build a website as if the user doesn't have JavaScript enabled to ensure its usable without it and I add my JavaScript afterwards. This way you don't have to worry about any complicated redevelopments.

I think you're likely to have to do a lot of work on this particular clients site as it sounds like its JavaScript heavy and since you can't detect whether JavaScript is enabled very easily (or at all?) You're going to have to make sure the website renders in a managable way then add your JS.

Comment: +1 exactly what I was about to suggest. If your website isn't **a JavaScript application**, it should be able to **work** without JavaScript, it may not look as pretty, but it will work.